# How to sum multiple rows in SQL which has different values in the adjacent column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum

Lets say I have following table:

| fuel | units | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| diesel | gallon | 30 |
| lpg | gallon | 20 |
| cng | gallon | 50 |
| diesel | liter | 10 |

And I want to perform a select query in SQL server which sums the value of 'diesel' field. diesel in liter gets multiplied by a conversion factor and the
Result should look like this.

| fuel | units | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| diesel | gallon | 40 |

I am able to convert diesel from liter to gallons and get the value but i cannot separate diesel in gallons from the table and add it to diesel in liter after conversion.

Comment: Please ignore the dotted lines in the first table.

Comment: `SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN units = 'gallon' THEN  total / 3.78541 ELSE total END) FROM table WHERE fuel = 'diesel'` this should give you the total liters.

Comment: But this does not add the two values.

Comment: What i want the result to be is, When the fuel type = 'diesel' and units = 'gallons' then the total as it is (which is 30)  + when the fuel type = 'diesel' and units = 'liter' then multiply 10 and i want the result to be returned as diesel = 40

Comment: it will sum up all the matching values, and convert any gallons to liters along the process, which you can then convert to gallons, or modify the condition to do the opposite (converting to gallons instead of liters.) If this is not what you're looking for, then you need to provide an expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing only LITERS and GALLONS then a conditional aggregation should to the trick

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b768c15e68b40a787e16eb78a203720b)**

```
Select fuel
      ,units = 'gallon'
      ,total = sum( case when units='liter' then total * 0.264172 else total end )
 From  YourTable
 Group By fuel
```

**Results**

```
fuel    units   total
cng     gallon  50.000000
diesel  gallon  32.641720
lpg     gallon  20.000000
```

**EDIT JUST FOR FUN.  Let's add Barrels as well**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([fuel] varchar(50),[units] varchar(50),[total] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('diesel','gallon',30)
,('lpg','gallon',20)
,('cng','gallon',50)
,('diesel','liter',10)
,('diesel','barrel',1)
 
Select fuel
      ,units = 'gallon'
      ,total = sum( case units when 'liter' then 0.264172 
                               when 'barrel' then 42
                         else 1 
                     end * Total )
 From  @YourTable
 Group By fuel
```

**2nd Results**

```
fuel    units   total
cng     gallon  50.000000
diesel  gallon  74.641720
lpg     gallon  20.000000
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I tried the above query but it is not returning the right result for me. I am doing this in SQL server

Comment: the check i am doing is when units - liter then convert it and add that value to diesel in gallons and return that as the result.

Comment: SELECT fuel, units, 
SUM(CASE WHEN units = 'liter' and fuel = 'diesel'
THEN (total*conversion_factor) END) AS total
FROM @yourtable
GROUP BY units, fuel;

Comment: What the above query does is, it converts diesel to gallons and returns two separate rows for diesel; it does not add the two values and return one value for diesel

Comment: @jack_sparrow Color me confused.  That is what we are doing.  I suspect "diesel" may have some control characters.   try SELECT DISTINCT  FUEL FROM YOURTABLE WHERE FUEL IS LIKE 'diesel%'    If you get more than one row, than diesel is not distinct

Comment: @jack_sparrow  Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=feab52c7f6232d2c41c77bba0fc5a95a  Notice I added a CHAR(13) to the last row

Comment: Thank you @John Cappelletti